# How can I rename my main class in the NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using NetBeans IDE and have created a new project. The new project includes a Main.java.

Is it necessary to have it named Main.java, or can I rename the Main.java into another name?  If so, how can I do this? When I try to right-click Main.java, there is no rename option.  I thought it was possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a menu item called

> Refactor --> Rename

[Link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring) from NetBeans Wiki

Your name can be anything, as long as you have a

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

in it (This is only if you want this class to be the entry point when you run your application).

Comment: Cool.. it works.  Seems kinda like Microsoft Word's Find & Replace.

Comment: @O_O : Yes. Refactoring is very powerful -- especially when you have hundreds of files and references.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the file `<whatever you like>.java`, but the name of the class in that file must match the new name you give to the file.

So if you rename the file to MyCoolClass.java, you *also* have to change the class from `public class Main` to `public class MyCoolClass`.

Answer (score 2):

you can even have the simpler way,click on the file_name.java in the Projects panel,wait for a sec and click one more time (just as you rename any other folder/file).It will allow you to replace the new name and then it will popup a window asking whether you want to refactor or not...

Answer (score 0):

you got to use the refractor, as it is the safest way to do such actions